# How can I store a "comment" in an AWS Elasticsearch instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'd like to store a bit of meta data such as when the index was created and by whom (a username at my organisation). Is there an easy way to do this, factoring in how locked down an AWS version of Elasticsearch is?

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to adding fields to the document? It would be fairly simple to use a script that knows the user and takes a document and gets the time, adds the meta data to the document and proceeds to add the document to the ES library.

for example the following code works as long as your data doesn't include any double quotes or quoted : True : False or: None ::

```
# coding: utf-8
true = True
false = False
null = None

import sys

inDoc = sys.argv[1]

#print inDoc
parts = inDoc.split(".")
if(parts[len(parts)-1].lower()=="json"):
    with open(inDoc,"r") as INDOC:
        doc = INDOC.read()
else:
    doc = inDoc

del inDoc

pyDoc = eval(doc)

del doc

pyDoc["#Creator"] = "<Your_Name>"
import time
import datetime
pyDoc["#CreatedAt"] = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

doc = str(pyDoc)

del pyDoc

esDomain = "search-movies-4f3nw7eiia2xiynjr55a2nao2y.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/movies/movie/tt0116996"

import os
command = "curl -XPUT "+esDomain+" -d '"+str(doc).replace(": True",": true").replace(": False",": false").replace(": None",": null").replace("'",'"')+"'"

del doc
del esDomain

#print (command)
os.system(command)

del command
```

you would have the document you wish to add saved as newDoc.json and run the following command

```
python AddWithStamps.py ./newDoc.json
```

After navigating to the directory of your documents. Alternatively you can run:

```
python AddWithStamps.py '{"Some": "Document"}'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python (I'm using Node) but what I assume is you are adding a field to every document in my index with the username and date?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a new index dedicated for my meta data instead of storing a whole extra field for every doc?

Comment: Well that would double the size of your indices... If you need to have multiple edits to a single index documented you could use a stack. This is a convenient way to do things except it isn't perfect. For one it uses the clients time and if someone with credentials to the table modify's it without using the provided wrappers your histories can be made inaccurate. Personally I have never been in charge of anything using IAMS https://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/ although I would be interested to know about what their user histories look like.